# Ubuntu on Inspiron 7559 — Cannot reboot

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, nouveau

My problem comes with two symptoms: 1st in booting I’m able to log in, but the system then freezes and I cannot input anything.

Second, and more common is the issue that displays after the computer auto opens the GNU GRUB and I select Ubuntu:

nouveau 0000:02:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554
[IBUS]
nouveau 0000:02:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08
[IBUS]
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 524312 (uid=121, gid=125, mode=0100600, size=51746)
/dev/sda1: clean, 135586/61054976 files, 5))8159/244190208

Sometimes the login menu opens after this but again, my system freezes.

As further context while installing I had to restart a bunch of times because the installer would freeze. Maybe 10x before it worked, but now I can’t reboot properly.

From what I’ve found online the issue is probably related to the nVidia graphics card on the Inspiron 7559. I’ve tried some of the solutions through the GRUB but haven’s had success. I’m trying to reinstall now with a USB, but it’s freezing on install. Any advice would be great, hopefully trying to re-install isn’t going to cause me more problems.

Comment: Dell typically needs UEFI update, if SSD, SSD firmware update & change drives from RAID/Intel SRT to AHCI. UEFI update may reset some settings. Often better to have fast boot & Secure Boot in UEFI off. With nVidia you will need nomodeset boot parameter. Post installation issues Ubuntu 18.04-Dell inspiron 7559
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072382/post-installation-issues-ubuntu-18-04-dell-inspiron-7559
Dell 7559 Install 16.04 or 18.04, best to skip all 16.04 info
https://connorkuehl.github.io/dell-inspiron-7559-linux-guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks oldfred. I think I’m on my way to resolving this now. Appreciate your help.